# Replace Numeric Columns of dataset from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that has many columns, I want to extract the numeric columns and replace with the mean of the columns and then these modified columns replacing the ones in the original dataframe.

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(include = ["number"]).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)
df.loc[df.select_dtypes(include = ["number"])] = df1
```

I managed to extract the numeric columns but I couldn't replace them, the idea is not to manually indicate which are those numeric columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to `assign` a new/changed `DataFrame`. This will only change the columns you altered.

```
new_df = df.assign(**df.select_dtypes('number').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))
```

If you want to preserve the original `DataFrame`, you can do it in steps:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns                                                                                                                                                  
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: Thanks men, you helped me a lot

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: FWIW, in the future you might consider always upvoting/accepting answers that helped you.